# Automapper in Webapi Controller Unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mocking, asp.net-web-api2, automapper

I have a controller method in my webapi project which calls a service method and converts the response of the service method into a Dto object for sending the response.
The controller looks something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(WebApiConfig.RootApiUri + "/v1/examplepost")]
    public async Task<List<Html1Dto>> examplepost([FromBody] SomeInfoDto someInfoDto)
    {

        var someInfo = _mapper.Map<SomeInfoDto, SomeInfo>(someInfoDto);

        return this._mapper.Map<List<Html1>, List<Html1Dto>>(await this._someService.SomeCall(someInfo));
    }
```

and the mock test like this :

```
   //Arrange
   var mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
   var mockSomeService = new Mock<ISomeService<Html1>>();

   mockSomeService.Setup(s => s.SomeCall(It.IsAny<SomeInfo>())).ReturnsAsync(
            new List<Html1>() {new Html1() {....}});
   SomeInfoDto mockSomeInfoDto = new SomeInfoDto()
        {
           ..
        };
        SomeInfo mockSomeInfo = new SomeInfo();
   mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<SomeInfoDto, SomeInfo>(mockSomeInfoDto))
                  .Returns(mockSomeInfo);
   mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<List<Html1>, List<Html1Dto>>(It.IsAny<List<Html1>>())).Returns(It.IsAny<List<Html1Dto>>);
   var someController = GetController(mockMapper.Object, mockSomeService.Object);
    //Act
    var result = await someController.examplePost(mockSomeInfoDto);
```

I am using automapper to map the objects with Dtos. When I debug this test, result comes as null. The mapping of incoming dto works fine. I suspect there is some issue with the service method setup. Anyhelp is appreciated.

Comment: One quick thing - don't mock AutoMapper. Really, it's pointless. It's like mocking JSON.Net or StringBuilder. Just use the real thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapper mock is the other way round

`mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<List<Html1>, List<Html1Dto>>(It.IsAny<List<Html1>>())).Returns(It.IsAny<List<Html1Dto>>);`

to the signature in the method

`this._mapper.Map<List<Html1Dto>, List<Html1>>(await this._someService.SomeCall(someInfo));`

Additionally, assuming that is correct in your actual code, then the other bit that could be causing you issue is that the return `It.IsAny<List<Html1Dto>>` which will be null as `default(List<HtmlDto>)` is null, return a concrete class there instead as below.

---

This call:

```
this._mapper.Map<List<Html1Dto>, List<Html1>>(await this._someService.SomeCall(someInfo));
```

Doesn't have a setup in the Unit Test, so will return null. You need to arrange that to, probably something like:

```
mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<List<Html1Dto>,  List<Html1>>(It.IsAny<List<Html1>>()))
.ReturnsAsync(new List<Html1Dto> { ... });
```

Comment: I already have such code in my test, forgot to add in the question, It's not working with this also. I have edited the question

Comment: Do you have a complete example you could share?

Comment: I couldn't post the exact original code, hence I have faked it. Except the objects mentioned, the code is pretty much the same. If you need any extra information please comment it and I will add it in the question.

Comment: What if you move the await this._someService.SomeCall(someInfo) to a variable on the line above and pass that variable in to the .Map method?

Comment: @stu : I was still getting result as null from the fix you mentioned. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @NikolaiDante : It was mistake in the question with the mapper mock, I have corrected it, however your suggestion of returning a concrete class worked for me. Thanks for your answer. I was doing that for someInfo but not for Html1.